# Chart,js Pie Chart can the gap between a pie chart and the legend be adjusted

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a pie chart using chart.js in my Ionic 4 / Angular application, with the following options...

```
        let options : ChartOptions = {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 20
            }
          },
```

My chart looks like the following, but I would like the gap as shown below to be smaller, ie the legend closer to the pie chart.

[image]

Is there any way to reduce this gap?

### Edit 1

I have just noticed it is due to the size of my view port. For example, on a phone screen:

[image]

Now if I make the vie responsive, and stretch the view, I can see the legend always stick to the **bottom of the view**, so when stretched to the chart is large the legend is now closer:

[image]

So, the legend us "docked" to the bottom of the view.

Comment: have you tried looking at the documentation? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html

padding: 10 in labels, should do it

Comment: Yes, I did see the padding, but it didn't quite work for me, it just changes the space between the legend box. I am adding some more information, as I can see now, that it is the shape of my viewport (eg on a Mobile device)

Answer (score 1):

I think the space might be due to your css. Try changing that. This solves your problem as well.

```
legend:{
position: 'bottom',
labels: {
          boxWidth: 20,
          padding: -10
        }
}
```

Comment: The padding didn't quite do what I was after (see edit I now added). I should have mentioned shape of the view port I was using..

Answer (score 0):

One propose solution (perhaps there is a better way - still be interested...)

I found, in my case, I could do this just by adjusting the bottom of my container.

Using the following markup..

```
    <div id='graphc'>
      <canvas (click)='updateClick($event)' #mygraph></canvas>
    </div>
```

and the following css

```
#graphc{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 120px; // <-- this moves it up
}
```

[image]

This at least does what I was after, though if I stretch, I do always have the gap....

Maybe I could make the css "dynamic" to fix this

[image]

Comment: This is a case to be handled by media queries. You have to specify the size of the container for different screens. I think you might have added some css here which is affecting the chart.

Comment: @DEVCNN - yes, I was thinking either maybe that, etc. so I am pretty sure it should be solvable now (just need to play a little more)